# How to unsubscribe Akka logs in run time

Tags: scala, akka, event-bus

I have my own Actor that subscribe to Akka logs using configuration

```
loggers = ["path.MyActor"]
```

`MyActor` Receiving the log events, but I would like to stop receiving them in run time.
Is there way to do that? (etc by getting the event bus of Akka logs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call [`system.eventStream`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#eventStream:akka.event.EventStream) to unsubscribe `MyActor`. For example:

```
import akka.event.Logging._

case object UnsubscribeFromLogging

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case InitializeLogger(_)                        => sender() ! LoggerInitialized
    case Error(cause, logSource, logClass, message) => // ...
    case Warning(logSource, logClass, message)      => // ...
    case Info(logSource, logClass, message)         => // ...
    case Debug(logSource, logClass, message)        => // ...

    case UnsubscribeFromLogging => context.system.eventStream.unsubscribe(self)
  }
}
```

The above example uses a custom `UnsubscribeFromLogging` message:

```
val myActor: ActorRef = ??? // reference to MyActor
myActor ! UnsubscribeFromLogging
```

You could pass the reference to `MyActor` to the `unsubscribe` method from another actor:

```
val myActor: ActorRef = ??? // reference to MyActor
context.system.eventStream.unsubscribe(myActor)
```

Either way, you need a reference to `MyActor`. You can obtain this by determining `MyActor`'s path (for example, have `MyActor` print `self.path`) and passing this path to [`context.actorSelection`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#identifying-actors-via-actor-selection).